# BigQuery Not Running MySQL Query - Error " Encountered "" at line 17, column 2."

Tags: google-bigquery

I run the following query and get the error:

> " Encountered "" at line 17, column 2."

The SQL query runs in MySQL but not in BigQuery. How can I resolve this?

```
SELECT
  vtbl_co.id,
  tbl_co.ypname,
  tbl_co.ypwww,
  tbl_co_1.ypname AS compname,
  tbl_co_1.ypwww,
  tbl_comps.dist,
  tbl_stats_1.grain_count,
  tbl_stats_1.grain_images,
  tbl_stats_1.grain_dq,
  tbl_stats.grain_count AS compgrainct,
  tbl_stats.grain_images AS compgrainimg,
  tbl_stats.grain_dq
FROM
  tbl_stats AS tbl_stats_1
RIGHT JOIN (((
(tbl_comps
        INNER JOIN
          tbl_co
        ON
          tbl_comps.idk_prospect = tbl_co.id)
      INNER JOIN
        tbl_co AS tbl_co_1
      ON
        tbl_comps.idk_peer = tbl_co_1.id)
    LEFT JOIN (tbl_stats
      RIGHT JOIN
        tbl_url
      ON
        tbl_stats.id_url = tbl_url.id)
    ON
      tbl_co_1.id_url = tbl_url.id)
  LEFT JOIN
    tbl_url AS tbl_url_1
  ON
    tbl_co.id_url = tbl_url_1.id)
ON
  tbl_stats_1.id_url = tbl_url_1.id
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to wrap parentheses around your `JOIN` sources, you need to make the `JOIN` source the result of a subselect, for example:

```
[...]
FROM
  tbl_stats AS tbl_stats_1
RIGHT JOIN (((
(SELECT [...]
 FROM tbl_comps
    INNER JOIN
      tbl_co
[...]
```